# xamarin.ios mac build host version not compatible with local version

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have installed on my visual studio and my mac . When I try to connect to my mac from visual studio I get this error :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b63jF.jpg

What should I do ?Should i change version of my mac xamarin or VS?

Thanks

Comment: The most recent stable release of Xamarin.iOS is 9.0.1.29, the current alpha release is Xamarin.iOS 9.2.0.84, either way your versions of 8.x are out of date (https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-ios-9-support-service-release-1/) but if you need to stay on 8.x, I would update your build host to 8.10 (https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-5-service-release-4/)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do Check for Updates on both Mac and PC for Xamarin.

- Mac: "Xamarin Studio" -> Check for Updates
- PC: Tools -> Options ->
  Xamarin -> Other -> Check for Updates

Comment: What to do if we don't have Xamarin Studio on mac ? In that case, how to update Xamarin iOS on mac ?

Answer (score 0):

The most recent stable release of Xamarin.iOS is 9.0.1.29. The current alpha release is Xamarin.iOS 9.2.0.84, either way your versions of 8.x on VS and the OS-X build host are 'out of date'.

- https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-ios-9-support-service-release-1/

**If you need to stay on 8.x**, I would update your OS-X build host to 8.10 as it was the last stable service release of 8.x

- https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-5-service-release-4/

Comment: Thanks , I think I would stay with 8.x . Could you tell me how to update to  OS-X build host to 8.10 ??

Comment: I would just connect Xamarin support as they can provide the download link to that pkg installer

Answer (score 0):

Just log in to your account on http://xamarin.com and then you can find the Downloads section in your account page, where you can click “View all versions” to see all versions, including 8.*. That should help you find a matching version.